# Ayuda con una simple suma en C#

Tags: c#

estoy teniendo un problema con una formula en c#.
Yo tengo una cantidad de kilos de arroz.

```
De 1 a 20kilos el valor es de = 3000
de 20 a 50 kilos el valor es de = 5000;
y mas de 50 kilos el valor es de: 2000 por cada 20 kilos adicionales. (solo necesito el numero entero)
```

De 1 a 20 es facil de hacer, al igual que de 20 a 50. Pero como hago de mas de 50 kilos?

¿Debo hacer cantidad de kilos - 50 ? pero luego no sé cómo seguir

ayuda por favor

Comment: Hola bienvenido a StackOverflow, añade tu código para que se pueda echarte una mano y ver que es lo que llevas hecho

Comment: cantidad de kilos - 50 = (exceso sobre 50). (exceso sobre 50) / 20 =  (multiplicador). Redondear multiplicador al entero superior. ejemplo : 0.2 = 1; 0.1 = 1; 3.4 = 4. Resultado = (multiplicador redondeado) * 2000 + 5000.   Ejemplo para 60 kilos : (60 - 50) = 10(exceso).  10 / 20 = 0.5(multiplicador) , redondear multiplicador = 1. Resultado = 1 * 2000 + 5000 = 7000.

Comment: @Lobos, creo que me queda claro, pero  no entiendo lo del multiplicador, no seria una suma? En el sentido de que claro, estoy sumando los 2000 y los 5000 de los primeros intervalos, pero luego no deberia sumar la cantidad de kilos del tercer intervalo? porque lo has multiplicado?

Comment: Por cada 20 kilos adicionales se agregan 2000. El multiplicador es la cantidad de veces que se agregaran esos 2000.  Por ejemplo, si son 100 kilos, el exceso sobre 50 son 50. En el exceso (50) hay 2.5 veces 20 (20,20,10) entonces el multiplicador será 3 (2.5 aproximado), los primeros 20 extras = 2000, los segundos 20 extras = 2000 y los 10 extras = 2000. Eso hace precio base 5000 + 6000 ( 2000 por cada 20 kilos extra)

Comment: Si estás en el tercer caso ya no necesitas los otros dos, ya sabes que el precio base es de 5000 y a eso le sumas 2000 por cada 20 kilos de exceso.

Comment: Tu problema es la matematica o el codigo?

Comment: Creo que mi respuesta se bugeo, pero mi problema es en ambas. Estoy intentando implementar el codigo, pero al momento de truncar me aparece lo siguiente "La llamada es ambigua entre los metodos o las propiedades siguientes:  math.truncate(decimal) y math.truncate(double)

Comment: aqui esta el codigo (he usado otros valores mas pequeños)
double extra = 0;

                double final = 0;

                extra = Math.Ceiling(((contr.numeroAsistentes - 50) / 20));
                final = 5 + (extra * 2);
                recargo = (int)(extra + final);